# HttpWebRequest Windows 10 KB3147458 - Internal Server Error

Tags: server, httpwebrequest, internal

I have an old legacy application which has been using HttpWebRequest to consume a SOAP Web Service.

Everything was fine until the latest update KB3147458 in Windows 10, which occasionally sends Internal Server Errors when running the following:

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();

Until now I only found two possible solutions:

Uninstall the KB3147458 and try again. Update my project to Framework 4.6.

Has anyone else came across this issue?

Thanks in advance.